# TextMeshPro doesn't render text on Android when installed through adb or AndroidStudio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've created a simple app which uses TextMeshPro to render a text in a 3d world space. When i deploy the game to my Android device using Unity3D "Build And Run" the text is rendered properly, but when I either install it through adb as "adb install game.apk" or through Android Studio it stops rendering any text, as in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qurZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOaQi.png

I'm also getting following error message:

```
2020-10-25 16:14:28.784 1418-3751/? E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at TMPro.TMP_Text.GetStyle (System.Int32 hashCode) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TMPro.TMP_Text.get_textStyle () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TMPro.TMP_Text.StringToInternalParsingBuffer (System.String sourceText, TMPro.TMP_Text+UnicodeChar[]& internalParsingArray) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TMPro.TMP_Text.ParseInputText () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TMPro.TextMeshPro.OnPreRenderObject () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TMPro.TextMeshPro.Rebuild (UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdate update) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TMPro.TMP_UpdateManager.DoRebuilds () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Canvas+WillRenderCanvases.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
 
(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

any ideas?

Unity 2019.4.8f1

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Forgot to include .obb archive file when installing app through adb or Android Studio. As I don't have big project I've disabled `Split Application Binary` so my .obb file would not get generated.